# Unable to fail the test by timeout using the mocha with protractor

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, protractor, performance-testing

I found on mocha web site then we can set the timeout fot it blocks, but looks like it doesn't work for me.

```
describe('something', function () {
    this.timeout(500);
    it('should take less than 500', function (done) {
        setTimeout(done, 500);
        browser.get('#/dashboard');
    });
})
```

Run result:

```
something
  √ should take less than 500 <9849>
```

Is it posible to get the actual test timeout and compare it?
Or I should use expect() to fail the test?

Thank you for any ideas in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem in my **exports.config**:

```
  mochaOpts: {
    reporter: 'good-mocha-html-reporter',
    slow: 5000,
    enableTimeouts: true
  }
};
```

enableTimeouts was in **false** state.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set different timeouts for each it that will override the exports.config value like this-

`it('should take less than 500', function (done) {
        setTimeout(done, 500);
        browser.get('#/dashboard');
    },500);`